# Pick colors in DC.js by CSS instead of hardcoding

Tags: css, svg, colors, dc.js

Is there a way to give the charts color-classes, instead of hardcoding the colors in the javascript?

I would really like it if I were able to style my charts using CSS alone

Comment: Sure, lots of SVG does that. What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: The DC.js api, I have not found any clues as where to set classes for colors.

Comment: Cross-linking to feature request: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/723. Indeed it doesn't look like there's any way to do it today.  I have some questions what it would look like, which I'll ask on the request